# How to transfer information about original mesh

Tags: geometry-nodes, subdivision-surface

I have an icosphere.

[image]

I need to apply a "Subdivision Surface" modifier to it and then split the edges, but not all the edges, just the edges according to the original mesh.

[image]

it is not suitable for me to apply "split edges" before "subdivision surface", then blender also rounds the corners.

[image]

I need to transfer information about the "old" edges somehow, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you would simply have to mark the edges before the subdivision with a boolean value using the `Capture Attribute` node.

You can then use this captured values after the node `Subdivision Surface` as a selection for the node `Split Edges`.

[image]

Comment: niiiiiiiiiiice ! ;) +1